# Performance of search in java list vs on database records using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Now I have a situation where I need to make some comparisons and result filtration that is not very simple to do, what I want is something like Lucenes search but only I will develop it, it is not my decision though I would have gone with Lucene.

What I will do is:

1. Find the element according to full word match of a certain field, if not then check if it starts with it the check if it just contains.
2. Every field has its weight according to matching case(full->begins->contains) and its priority to me.
3. After one has matched I will also check the weight of the other fields as well to make a final total row weight.
4. Then I will return an Map of both rows and their weights.

Now I realized that this is not easy done by hibernate's HQL meaning I would have to run multiple queries to do this.

So my question is should I do it in java meaning should I retrieve all records and do my calculations to find my target, or should I do it in hibernate by executing multiple queries? which is better according to performance and speed ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the right answer is "it depends": how many words, what data structure, whether the data fits in memory, how often you have to do the search, etc.

I am inclined to think that a database is a better solution, even if Hibernate is not part of it.  You might need to learn how to write better SQL.  Perhaps the dynamic SQL that Hibernate generates for you isn't sufficient.  Proper JOINs and indexing might make this perform nicely.

There might be a third way to consider: Lucene and indexing.  I'd need to know more about your problem to decide.

Comment: well lets just say its the management's decision not to use a third party API, so am stuck with this, and there is not time to learn a new  API, but the thing is i have many different scenarios of matching and weighing the match and so displaying the final result.

Comment: New API?  JDBC is not a new API; neither is SQL.

Comment: So don't try it.  I'd recommend a non-Hibernate approach with some smarter SQL.